# Node.js Oracle DB connection pool. How to log how many connections are currently open

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, connection-pooling, node-oracledb

I am new to Node JS world. I am using a Oracle DB in my application and creating a connection pool. Using this connection pool to query the DB. Application is working fine but For my testing, I need to log how many connections are open after every query.

How can I log how many connections are open.

Below is my code to create connection pool:

```
async function bbUserPool() {
  try {
     await oracledb.createPool({
        user          : config.user,
        password      : config.password,  
        connectString : config.connectString,
        poolAlias     : 'userpool',
        poolIncrement : 10,
        poolMax       : 20,
        poolMin       : 20
      });   
  } 
  catch (err) {
     console.error("Connection Pool Error:" + err.message)     
  }
}
```

How can I log how many connections are open.

Answer (score 0):

The node-oracledb documention [Connection Pool Monitoring](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpoolmonitor) has useful information.

> Pool attributes connectionsInUse and connectionsOpen always provide
> basic information about an active pool:
>
> ```
> const pool = await oracledb.createPool(...);
>
> . . .
>
> console.log(pool.connectionsOpen);   // how big the pool actually is
> console.log(pool.connectionsInUse);  // how many of those connections are held by the application
> ```

This is from the pool implementation's point of view.  The `connectionsOpen` value is how many 'pipes' (for want of a better word) have been established to the database.  In your example, I would expect this to be 20 in normal operation.  The `connectionsInUse` value is the count of `getConnection()` calls that have not had an explicit or implicit (at end of scope) corresponding `connection.close()` call.